# How to delete spaces in printing the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, input

```
def lexemize_Ari_Exp():
    
    arithmeticExpression = input("Write an Arithmetic Expression: ")
    list_Of_Arit_Exp = []
  
    for x in arithmeticExpression:
        list_Of_Arit_Exp.append(x)
    print(list_Of_Arit_Exp)
        
lexemize_Ari_Exp()
```

#Input: x + 1

#Output: ['x', ' ', '+', ' ', '1']

Comment: What exactly is the output you're looking for?

Comment: Just add .split() function at the end of your input and delete the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If each element of the expression is divided by a space you can simply use the `split()` function:

```
def lexemize_Ari_Exp():
    
    arithmeticExpression = input("Write an Arithmetic Expression: ")
    list_Of_Arit_Exp = arithmeticExpression.split()
    
    print(list_Of_Arit_Exp)
        
lexemize_Ari_Exp()
```

Example of output:

```
Write an Arithmetic Expression: x + 1
['x', '+', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an if statement like this:

```py
for x in arithmeticExpression:
    if not x == ' ':
        list_Of_Arit_Exp.append(x)
```

This is because your for loop iterates on every single character of the input string, and x just represents the character in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove (list, toRemove):
     for i in range (0, list.count (toRemove)):
         list.pop (list.index (toRemove))
     return list
```

Use this function to remove the elements you want from a list

```
list = [0, 1, 0]
print (remove (list, 0))#Remove all the 0 from the list
```

Works with every type (int, float, string...)